# Calculate mean based on range within a cell

Tags: r

I'm new to R (and Stackoverflow, so sorry about the formatting of the question), and working on an assignment for class.

As part of this, I have a data frame with a `chr` column of the number of participants in an event. Some of these are whole values, whereas some are ranges.

To proceed, I need to replace the ranges with the midrange based on the values within the cell.

As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(event=c('Football', 'Basketball', 'Football', 'Tennis', 'Basketball'),
                 num_participants=c(157, 220, 175-189, 190-220, 320-350)
```

How would I replace the ranges with the mean of the max/min of the range, while maintaining the singular values (e.g., 157 & 220)?

Comment: Apologies for lack of clarity. The idea would be to either create a new column which would carry the singular values (157, 220 in the example) and convert the ranges (175-189: 182, 190-220: 205, 320-350: 335), or to replace the ranges within the initial column with the midrange of the given values.

Comment: Sorry, your example didn't had quotes around it, which created a different dataset

Comment: what i meant is that you should have used `"175-189"` instead of `175-189` as these are string values

Comment: Understood, I know better for next time! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the column into left-side and right-side using `separate`. Since the separate is a function used to deal with strings, we have to change the column type to numeric and calculate the `mean` statisitcs.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(event=c('Football', 'Basketball', 'Football', 'Tennis', 'Basketball'),
                 num_participants=c("157", "220", "175-189", "190-220", "320-350")) 

df %>% 
  separate(col = num_participants, sep = "-", into = c("min", "max")) %>%
  mutate(max = as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(max), min, max)),
         min = as.numeric(min),
         mean = (min+max)/2) 
#
       event min max mean
1   Football 157 157  157
2 Basketball 220 220  220
3   Football 175 189  182
4     Tennis 190 220  205
5 Basketball 320 350  335
```

Note that separate will create missing value when there is no delimeter found in the observation. Example showed below :

```
> df %>% 
+   separate(col = num_participants, sep = "-", into = c("min", "max"))

#
       event min  max
1   Football 157 <NA>
2 Basketball 220 <NA>
3   Football 175  189
4     Tennis 190  220
5 Basketball 320  350

Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [1, 2].
```

I replace the missing in column `max` to the same value as `min`.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `strsplit` to split at the `-`, convert the `list` elements to `numeric` and get the `mean`

```
df$num_participants <- sapply(strsplit(df$num_participants, '-'),
     \(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
```

---

Or another option is to read the column with `read.table` and use `rowMeans`

```
df$num_participants <- rowMeans(read.table(text = df$num_participants,
     header = FALSE,
     sep = '-', fill = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
df$num_participants
[1] 157 220 182 205 335
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(event = c("Football", "Basketball", "Football", 
"Tennis", "Basketball"), num_participants = c("157", "220", "175-189", 
"190-220", "320-350")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```